# PHP: Passing info to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, comet, dhtml

say, my PHP script needs some time to calculate its operations. I need to keep the client informed about the operation progress. An example can be PHP based file download, where I need to provide to client estimated time needed to finish the download, and the amount of data that needs to be copied.

In PHP I can calculate all the needed information. However, how to regularly update the client with this info?

Ideally, I would like to dynamically update JavaScript variable from within my PHP script. I read that this is not possible, so what options do I have then?

Possibilities that come to my mind:

- Should I do regular AJAX calls from within my JavaScript into the PHP script to get the progress info?
- Should I study for me yet unknown COMET methodology

Do the two above possibilities make sense? Is there any other more practical solution available?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both of those options make sense.

There are lots of different COMET-style techniques, but one of the simplest is a long-running `iframe`. You have a PHP page that monitors the progress of the operation, and outputs something like this at regular intervals:

```
<script>parent.updateProgress(relevantUpdateInfo);</script>
```

...where `relevantUpdateInfo` is the information about the progress, and `updateProgress` is a global function on the page containing the `iframe` that shows the updated information in the UI.

When outputting the `script` tags, be sure to `flush` the output.

Comment: hi. Thanks for the info. It was just OK to point me to the right direction. From now, I can go and study long-running COMET style, as it looks to be better alternative as issuing regular AJAX calls.